# co-semisimple module and its radical

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

A left $R$-module $M$ is said to be co-semisimple, if every proper submodule of $M$ is an intersection of maximal submodules. Also, the radical of $M$ denoted by $Rad(M)$ is the intersection of all maximal submodule of $M$.

I want to prove that $M$ is co-semisimple if and only if $Rad(M)=(0)$. Can anyone help me?

My idea is to prove by assuming the the radical is not zero.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $Rad(M)=\bigcap \{N\leq M$  $\vert$ $N$ is maximal$\}$

I will prove: $M$ is co-semisimple iff every nonzero quotient of $M$ has zero radical.

First, take $K\lt M$ a proper submodule.

Since $M$ is co-semisimple $K=\bigcap N_\alpha$, each of wich is maximal.

By the correspondence theorem $N_\alpha$ appears in $M/K$ in the form $N_\alpha /K$ (and they are maximal submodules of the quotient), then $Rad(M/K)=\bigcap\{N/K$$\vert$$N/K$ is maximal$\}=\bigcap (N_\alpha/K)=0$.

Take $K=0$, since $M/0$ is isomorphic to $M$, we have $Rad(M)=0$

For the other direction take $M/K\neq 0$, then $Rad(M/K)=0$ implies $K$ is the intersection of maximal submodules by definition of $Rad$.

Comment: you mean $\cap N_\alpha/K=0/K$, the zero submodule of $M/K$.

Comment: Of course, the zero submodule of the quotient.

Answer (score 1):

It's wrong.

Take $R=\Bbb Z$ and $M=\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$.

$M$ has only one (non-trivial) proper submodule, $I=\left\{ \bar0,\bar2 \right\}$, $Rad(M)=I\neq (0)$ and $M$ is co-semisimple.

Comment: The OP did not specify "non-trivial" in his question. Maybe it's a mistake on their part, but it seems that their definition does imply that $\{0\}$ is an intersection of maximal submodules, so it is the radical.

Comment: Are the two sided wrong? because I read a paper 'classical Zariski topology of modules and spectral spaces I ' and in Theorem 2.9 of it he used this information.(http://ieja.net/files/papers/volume-4/Volume-2--2007/7-V4-2008.pdf) Can you look to it please?